# How do I create a link_to tag with both class and data fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, ruby-on-rails-5, link-to, custom-data-attribute

I want to create a Rails link_to tag that will ultimately spawn a dialog box and so it just link to "#".  However, I would like it to have a class and data attribute.  But when I try this

```
<%= link_to "What's This?", "#", {class: "more_info"}, :data => { :more_info => 'mt_hashes_info' } %>
```

I get the error

```
wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..3)
```

What's the right way to construct this link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what it should look like:

`<%= link_to "What's This?", "#", {:class => "more_info", :data => { :more_info => 'mt_hashes_info' }} %>`

Class and Data both go into the same options hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply like this

```
<%= link_to "What's This?", "#", class: "more_info", data: { more_info: "mt_hashes_info" } %>
```

the generated HTML

```
<a class="more_info" data-more-info="mt_hashes_info" href="#">What's This?</a>
```

With `confirmation` dialog

```
<%= link_to "What's This?", "#", class: "more_info", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

the generated HTML

```
<a class="more_info" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="#">What's This?</a>
```

You can find more the [`link_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from the heart of Redmine:

```
link_to(l(:button_archive), archive_project_path(project, :status => params[:status]), :data => {:confirm => l(:text_are_you_sure)}, :method => :post, :class => 'icon icon-lock')
```

Sorry about the run-on statement; you know Redmine! But note both :data and :class are peers of the same Hash...